# Get "as low as" price on product list for grouped products with tier prices

Tags: magento2.2, grouped-products, tierprice

Situation: a grouped product with 2 associated simple products:

> - Product 1: normal price 10 euro. Buy 10 for 8 euro.
> - Product 2: normal price 15 euro. Buy 10 for 12 euro.

Current behavior: product listing with price: 10 euro.

**Expected result:** product listing with price 10 euro and "as low as" 8 euro.

How do I implement the "as low as" tier price for grouped products?